# Average in order by clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
   Field1
   AVG(Field2) as Field2, 
   AVG(Field3) as Field3, 
   AVG(Field4) as Field4 
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Field1
ORDER BY Field2 DESC, Field3 DESC, Field4 DESC
```

How to (if is possible) order with average of the three fields?
I want to make a single order after getting an average of three fields. For example:

```
...
ORDER BY (Field2 + Field3 + Field4) / 3
```

Comment: Order what? Your query only returns one row.

Comment: is null possible in any of the fields? How would you want to handle those ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To sort on the average of Field1 + Field2 + Field3 you can either add a new field and sort on that.

```
select Field1,   
       avg(Field2) as AField2, 
       avg(Field3) as AField3, 
       avg(Field4) as AField4,
       avg(Field2+Field3+Field4) as Sort
from Table1
group by Field1
order by Sort desc
```

Or you can put your query in a sub-query and sort on the sum of the fields in the outer query.

```
select T.Field1,
       T.AField2,
       T.AField3,
       T.AField4
from (select Field1,   
             avg(Field2) as AField2, 
             avg(Field3) as AField3, 
             avg(Field4) as AField4
      from Table1
      group by Field1) as T
order by T.AField2 + T.AField3 + T.AField4 desc
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
   AVG(Field1) as AvgField1, 
   AVG(Field2) as AvgField2, 
   AVG(Field3) as AvgField3 
FROM Table1
   ORDER BY AvgField1 DESC, AvgField2 DESC, AvgField3 DESC
```

OR:

```
SELECT 
   AVG(Field1) as Field1, 
   AVG(Field2) as Field2, 
   AVG(Field3) as Field3 
FROM Table1
   ORDER BY AVG(Field1) DESC, AVG(Field2) DESC, AVG(Field3) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @sllev. Is this for both queries or just one of them? Do you have a reference as to why there are significant problems so that I can research?

Comment: I think @sllev believes your second query will run the aggregates twice, which is incorrect.

Comment: @JNK: I assumed that order by will calculate AVG one more time for each of columns, just can correct myself that this would be not a significant problems. I should recall my comment, I was wrong because ORDER BY applies to final select data set and this will be simple single integer per column so no AVG calculations at all

Comment: Just removed my commend and realized that this could confuse visitors by JNK comment because now it looks like he is saying about this particular answer, how can I restore original comment or how to correct this situation?

Comment: I removed my comment too, so we are back to where we started now.

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH Input(Field1, Field2, Field3)
AS
(
SELECT     
      AVG(Field1) as Field1,     
      AVG(Field2) as Field2,     
      AVG(Field3) as Field3  
    FROM Table1    
)
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 
FROM Input    
ORDER BY Field1 DESC, Field2 DESC, Field3 DESC
```

Comment: Ok, but i want to make a single order after getting an average of three fields.